# SQL Count from two tables using order by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, let's say Customer and Supplier. And let's say the structure looks like below:

```
Customer
--------------------
ProductID|CustomerID|
+--------+----------+
|   1    |   5000   |
|   1    |   5001   |
|   1    |   5002   |
|   2    |   5003   |
|   3    |   5004   |
|   1    |   5005   |
|   4    |   5006   |

Supplier
-----------------
ProductID|SupplierID|
+--------+----------+
|   1    |   3000   |
|   1    |   3001   |
|   2    |   3002   |
|   2    |   3003   |
|   4    |   3004   |
|   5    |   3005   |
|   6    |   3006   |
```

Now I need to write query which gives counts based on ProductID. So result should be like

```
ProductID| Count(Customer Table) | Count(Supplier Table) |
+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|   1    |          4            |         2             |
|   2    |          1            |         2             |
|   3    |          1            |         0             |
|   4    |          1            |         1             |
|   5    |          0            |         1             |
|   6    |          0            |         1             |
```

This tables are just scenario. My actual tables are very different. But answer for this will be good enough to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  ProductID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CustomerCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SupplierCount
FROM
    (
        SELECT ProductID, CustomerID AS ID, 'C' AS Source FROM Customer
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ProductID, SupplierID AS ID, 'S' AS Source FROM Supplier
    ) sub
GROUP   BY ProductID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83011/4)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ PRODUCTID ║ CUSTOMERCOUNT ║ SUPPLIERCOUNT ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════╣
║         1 ║             4 ║             2 ║
║         2 ║             1 ║             2 ║
║         3 ║             1 ║             0 ║
║         4 ║             1 ║             1 ║
║         5 ║             0 ║             1 ║
║         6 ║             0 ║             1 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `sub` is the `alias` given for the subquery.

Comment: Is it required? I don't see it being used anywhere?

Comment: I am used to give alias on subquery because other RDBMS will generate an error if you don't supply. I'm suprised oracle will alow subquery without alias http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83011/5

Comment: @BurhanKhalid good for you `:)` in mysql http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff81/2, in sql server http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26beb/1 both of them throws an exception when there is no alias defined on the subquery.

Comment: But @JW 웃 these is one problem with this approach. If suppose Product 'p' (which is present in 'Supplier' table) is not present in `Customer` table then this query will not show 0 for 'CustomerCount' column.
well we can add NVL function also in this query on both the sum column.

Comment: @pratikgarg yes right. but how do I know if such product `p` exist on the table? is there any table that holds a list of all products?

Comment: @JW 웃 sorry... my bad..
I have written 'product' instad of `supplier`

Comment: @pratikgarg don't feel to be sorry `:)` you have the point `:)`

Comment: But Now I realised that we are already cover this in `when .. case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is known as a "chasm trap", and requires that you aggregate the different tables to the level of the join column before executing the join.

You can do this through inline views, although a pair of common table expressions is a little more flexible for large data sets.

In this case, you could have a product that has been supplied but not purchased, so I'd outer join to make sure you don't lose any rows:

```
with
  cte_customers as (
    select   product_id,
             count(*) customer_count
    from     customer
    group by product_id),
  cte_suppliers as (
    select   product_id,
             count(*) supplier_count
    from     supplier
    group by product_id)
select
  s.product_id,
  s.supplier_count,
  coalesce(c.customer_count,0) customer_count
from
  cte_suppliers s left outer join 
  cte_customers on (s.product_id = c.product_id)
```